# How can I update the parent of a non-module with versions-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I have a project `x` with several modules, as usual in Maven, `x-api`, `x-impl` etc.

To keep things together, there is also a directory `x-ear`, which contains the EAR project, which will be deployed in the App Server. It's **not** part of the `<modules>` within the `x` POM, since it shouldn't take part in a normal reactor build. It does, however, have the same parent `x`.

Our release is done with the help of the versions-maven-plugin. Specifically, we create a new SNAPSHOT using

> mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT -DgenerateBackupPoms=false

Everything works well for the project and its modules (note that the modules don't have a version of their own, they inherit it from the project parent).

But, of course, the `x-ear` is not updated, since it's not part of the reactor build.

I tried a `cd` into the directory and using `versions.set` or `versions:update-parent`, but they don't work.

Does anyone know the magic command?  :-)

Comment: What happens if you `cd` into the directory and perform `mvn versions:set`? To my understanding this should work.

Comment: Sounds strange having the x-ear module being not part of the reactor? Which reason for that exist? What would you like to achieve ? Would you like to make your life easy ? Just put it into the modules list.

Comment: `versions:update-parent` has always worked for me.  If you want to grab the latest snapshot then you need to add `-DallowSnapshots=true` to the command line.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov: Since the EAR doesn't have a version of its own (it inherits from the parent), I get `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.0:set (default-cli) on project payment-ear: Project version is inherited from parent. -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @user944849: It doesn't work within a reactor build, since the parent has not yet been installed in the repo. I tried `mvn versions:update-parent -DallowSnapshots=true -DparentVersion=1.5.0-SNAPSHOT -DgenerateBackupPoms=false` but I get the result `[INFO] Current version of xyz:x:pom:1.3.0-SNAPSHOT is the latest.`

Comment: @khmarbaise: Well, it makes the build a bit longer and I don't necessarily want to deploy the EAR to the repo. But I guess you're right, treating it as normal module would make my life easier. Thanks for pointing to a rather obvious solution  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to khmarbaise for giving me the obvious answer: Just include the EAR as a normal module within the project.